# how can I link a shared object in C?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, shared-libraries

I made a simple program that uses a shared object, opening it with `dlopen()`. I also compiled and linked the shared object like below:

```
gcc -o libmylib.so libmylib.c -shared -fPIC -Wall

gcc -o program program.c -L. -lmylib -ldl -Wall
```

When I tried to run the program for the first time it said something like

```
cannot open libmylib.so: no such file or directory
```

so I searched the internet and found that I have to copy my shared object to `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/` in order for the program to run. So I did so, and it worked, but then I tried to do it in other ways and therefore I removed `libmylib.so` from the `/lib/i3686-linux-gnu/` directory. Now when I'm trying to run the program it shown no errors but keeps saying `Segmentation fault`. It is clear that the shared object is nowhere to be found, but how can I link it without copying anything?

I am using Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: Does the segmentation fault go away if you run `ldconfig` as root?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you compiled the program, you linked it properly; using `-L. -lmylib`. However, if it's not a standard system library, the execution environment needs to know where to look for it. One way you can do this is by using the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, like so:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./program
```

or

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
./program
```

Answer (score 8):

Read more about [shared libraries](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) and their [search paths](http://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/notes/rpath.html), and the [ld](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_ld.htm) command.

An alternative could be to register the "runtime" path used for searching library. You could use `gcc -Wl,-rpath . -o program program.c -L. -lmylib -ldl -Wall`

If your program is [dlopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen)-ing at run time some `*.so` file, you'll better pass the absolute file name to `dlopen` (or something like `"./foo.so"`). The [realpath](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realpath) function could help you.

There is even a command [chrpath](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chrpath) (which I just discovered) to use on an existing executable to change its run path.

There are security reasons (similar to those for `PATH`) to avoid putting the current directory in the run time path or the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.